# Adapter Not Populating From ArrayList Properly

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I created an adapter and am trying to populate a ListView with data from a String ArrayList. What I have noticed is that, every 4th, 8th, and 12th item that is stored in my ArrayList is not present on my ListView. If I remove the if/else (view == null) condition, everything works perfect except I receive a lint warning >> `Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling`

Here is my getView code that skips every 4th, 8th, 12th item

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select, null);        
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.rlLeft = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_left);
            holder.rlRight = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_right);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);   
            holder.tvLeftBubble = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_bubble);
            holder.tvRightBubble = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_right_bubble);
            holder.tvTitle.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getTitle());

            // set visibility gone on views
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                holder.rlLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvRightBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            } else {
                holder.rlRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
                holder.tvLeftBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            }

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Here is the code that WORKS and displays all items in my mArraySelect (String ArrayList) but gives me a lint warning on my inflate

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View view = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select, null);        
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.rlLeft = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_left);
            holder.rlRight = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_right);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);   
            holder.tvLeftBubble = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_bubble);
            holder.tvRightBubble = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_right_bubble);
            holder.tvTitle.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getTitle());

            // set visibility gone on views
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                holder.rlLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvRightBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            } else {
                holder.rlRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
                holder.tvLeftBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Anyone have an idea as to what I am missing in my first implementation to cause a skip in view? My mod condition is just to alternate two different views, and that works fine. Just that the 4, 8, and 12th item in my String ArrayList is not displaying. The array has only 12 items.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the following codes out side the outer most if block can resolve this issue-

```
// set visibility gone on views
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                holder.rlLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvRightBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            } else {
                holder.rlRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
                holder.tvLeftBubble.setText(mArrySelect.get(position).getMessage());
            }
```

Put it just above the return statement.

Comment: Heh! I don't quite understand it but this actually does work. Thanks!

Comment: You will get the answer once you think why we use the outer if block and the view holder object :)